# How to add CSS polygons at the end of HTML text

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight some text at the end of a `h2` with a `background-color`. Also I want to add some polygons at the end of the highlighted text that align with the highlighted text.

**Two examples with pros and cons:**

https://codepen.io/Sektin/pen/abPYZWW

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.grey {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 100% 100%, 65% 100%);
  background-color: grey;
  color: grey;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.red-2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.grey-2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: grey;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 100% 100%, 65% 100%);
}

.first {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.second {
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p>1.</p>
<p>Con: How to fix space between red and grey. 1px between blue and red not fully red.</p>
<p>Pro: No pixel alignment problems when using zoom or different browsers in y-axis.</p>
<h2>
  my headline including a lot of text so that it might break into another line and
  <span class="highlight">highlighted text</span><span class="red">gg</span><span class="grey">gg</span><span class="grey">gg</span>
</h2>
<br>
<p>2.</p>
<p>Con: Pixel alignment problems when using zoom and different browsers in y-axis. 1px between blue and red not fully red. 1px of bottom red not fully red. 1px of grey bottom not fully grey.</p>
<p>Pro: Adjustable space between red and grey</p>
<h2>
  my headline including a lot of text so that it might break into another line and
  <span class="wrapper">
    <span class="highlight">highlighted text</span>
  <span class="red-2"></span>
  <span class="grey-2 first"></span>
  <span class="grey-2 second"></span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

**The polygons should work dynamically with:**

- different font-sizes
- different text lengths and line breaks
- different browsers and browser view dimensions, e.g. mobile, tablet, desktop, etc...

I am always running into pixel alignment problems as shown in example 1 and 2.

[image: alignment problems when using browser zoom in Chrome]

Maybe there is a way to use SVGs to get a better result?

I hope someone can help. Any input or comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions here, one of which is to apply a pseudo-element with `background-image:linear-gradient`. For example, something like this:

```css
.highlight {
  --width: 2em;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:var(--width);
  position: relative;
  --part: 5.26;
}

.highlight:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 calc(-1 * var(--width)) 0 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    66.666deg,
    red calc(var(--part) * 6%),
    transparent calc(var(--part) * 6%),
    transparent calc(var(--part) * 7%),
    gray calc(var(--part) * 7%),
    gray calc(var(--part) * 9%),
    transparent calc(var(--part) * 9%),
    transparent calc(var(--part) * 10%),
    gray calc(var(--part) * 10%),
    gray calc(var(--part) * 12%),
    transparent calc(var(--part) * 12%)
  );
}
```

```html
<h2>
  my headline including a lot of text so that it might break into another line and <span class="highlight">highlighted text</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to make red and grey less pixilated in your example?

Comment: slightly changed the percentage values to get a more smooth look. Added your example with my changes to my codepen example